# Перестал работать Третий монитор (DisplayPort)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ноутбук HP 8470p.

Система ubuntu Linux somenet 4.16.0-041600-generic #201804012230 SMP Sun Apr 1 22:31:39 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

GUI тот что с пакета идет(наверное гном?)

Было подключено 2 монитора. 1 через VGA-VGA, второй DisplayPort-DVI(так же пробовал через переходник DP-VGA).
В общем все было ок, на выходных ноут постоял(обычно просто блочу юзера и все, в сон не бросаю, крышку не закрываю).
Прихожу, а 1 монитор не горит. как не пробовал, вернуть не получилось.
В лучшем случае каким то махинациями работает либо один либо второй монитор, но никак не 2 одновременно. Как только подключаю VGA, DP гаснет. Монитор менял, ноут тоже взял такой же, только винчестер перебросил, то есть, не проблема с железом по идее.

Возможно нужно драйвера переустановить? или как-то включить данный порт программно? потому что у меня были попытки его включить, и даже получилось(не помню что делал) но на след утро все стало так же печально.

---

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1366x768+0+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1366x768      59.80*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

---

```
~$ sudo gedit /var/log/Xorg.0.log
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Не удалось подключиться к: В соединении отказано

(gedit:27840): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

---

после переключения на х11

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1366x768      59.97*+  39.98  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: для начала вывод `xrandr` и `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` в студию... на всякий случай, самописный `xorg.conf` не используется?

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил вывод информации

Comment: ух.... убунта всё же перешла на wayland... извини, даже не предположу, куда с ним копать... случаем это всё началось не при обновлении ли до 4.16?

Comment: возможно. я пару раз принимал обновления. но не ребутал, все работало. до поры до времени. так полагаю тоже что это из-за обновления. товарищ смотрел и тоже так же сказал про wayland..

Comment: @Fat-Zer может можно откатится как-то?

Comment: вроде как говорят что если выйти к экрану авторизации там нажать на настройки то можно выбрать Ubuntu on X..чтототам. и как бы это будет убунту на Х. я так сделал. может это как то упростит задачу?

Comment: в принципе возможно всё, но откат на предыдущий релиз изнутри системы — это крайне не тривиальная задача, требующая значительного опыта и знаний... обычно проще переустановить со внешнего носителя с сохранением хомяка и некоторых файлов настроек/списка установленных пакетов (само собой также надо быть осторожным)... но руководство ни к тому ни к другому я писать не готов...

Comment: Как переключиться на X с wayland'а я тоже подсказать не могу... индикатором можно считать, например то что xrandr будет выводить нормальные имена выходов вместо `XWAYLAND0` и список доступных расширений.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76495/discussion-between-maxim-and-fat-zer).

Comment: @Fat-Zer  в общем я переключился на Х11, а что мне это дает?)

Comment: это проверяется так echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил вывод xrandr

Comment: теперь можно посмотреть адекватный xrandr и лог X'ов...ъ

Comment: монитор по DisplayPort'у явно не подключён, когда проверял аппаратную часть, проверял всё, и монитор, и кабель, и переходник?

Comment: да. монитор менял, кабель менял. сейчас без переходников напрямую кабель ДП-ДВИ

Comment: я в чат бросил лог

Comment: @Fat-Zer  ну вот только что подключил через переходник DP-VGA и кабель VGA_VGA второй внешний монитор. он заработал. но погас первый. который был ВГА-ВГА